# discord.js bot math not working right

Tags: javascript, discord

So with my bot when someone purges a channel I want to add one to the purge amount they have then split the first value off so it doesn't purge their command, However when I try to add 1 to the value of the argument passed it just puts the number behind the value... Any help, I' really crappy at JS so ye...

```
if (args[1]){
    var messagecount = args[1];
    var messagetotal = Math.floor(messagecount + 1); // Adding 1 to passed argument
    console.log(messagetotal); // Outputting to console, Console is reading the argument with 1 on the end EX: arg: 2 | output: 21
//  message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: messagecount}).then(messages => message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(messages => message.channel.send("Purged `" + messages.size + "` messages.")));
} else {
//  message.channel.send("Usage: !purge (Number)");
}
```

Comment: is messagecount a string? Maybe try parseInt(messagecount) + 1

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Yeah it was, I personally didn't know the difference because I'm new to JS, wigi helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that the exact content of `args[1]` is, but regarding your explanation of the bug, it seems that the value is a number formatted as a string.

The difference:

**String**

```
args[1] = "1";
console.log(args[1] + 1);
```

Output: `"11"`

**Integer**

```
args[1] = 1;
console.log(args[1] + 1);
```

Output: `2`

If you add a number to a string, it will be appended and not added mathematically.

To format your numeric string to an integer, replace

`var messagecount = args[1];`

through

`var messagecount = parseInt(args[1]);`

Answer (score -1):

```
const math = require('mathjs');

if (args.length > 0)
          if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
            message.reply('You do not have permission to use this command.')
          else {
            var amount = args.join(' '),
            total = math.evaluate(`${amount}+1`);
            message.channel.bulkDelete(total).catch(console.error);
          }
        else
          message.reply('You did not type an amount for me to delete.')
      break;
```